# Cannot Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: upgrade, ssh, 14.10

I'm an Ubuntu newbie, struggling HARD to figure out how I can upgrade from Ubuntu 14.10 to anything above. Just recently learned that the XX.04 distributions are where I want to be, ideally 16.04. I'm hosting in the cloud with Digital Ocean, so everything is through SSH. I've tried most commands that people recommend with no luck. I think I'm mostly hung up when it comes to checking/editing files within ssh. I'm sure this is not nearly enough information to receive actual help, so anyone willing to stoop to my level, I'm more than willing to provide any details you require to help out. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I have attempted the steps referenced in the article in the comments with the following results. Thank you for your prompt responses, but unfortunately no luck. This is not a duplicate, as my problem has not been resolved with the provided resources.

```
# sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates InRelease                   
Get:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg [933 B]       
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu InRelease                                       
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports InRelease             
Hit http://www.ubnt.com stable InRelease                             
Get:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release [63.5 kB]         
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic Release.gpg                         
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates Release.gpg                 
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu Release.gpg                                     
Get:3 http://www.ubnt.com stable/ubiquiti amd64 Packages [687 B]               
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports Release.gpg               
Get:4 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Sources [63.7 kB]    
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic Release                             
Get:5 http://www.ubnt.com stable/ubiquiti i386 Packages [687 B]                
Get:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Sources [2,107 B]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates Release                     
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports Release          
Get:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Sources [17.4 kB]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main Sources/DiffIndex         
Get:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Sources [2,384 B]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted Sources/DiffIndex   
Get:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages [212 kB]
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu Release                                         
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe Sources/DiffIndex          
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex        
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex       
Get:10 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages [8,496 B]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex 
Get:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages [79.8 kB]
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti amd64 Packages/DiffIndex               
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex   
Get:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,348 B]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex 
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti i386 Packages/DiffIndex       
Get:13 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages [210 kB]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex        
Get:14 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages [8,438 B]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex  
Get:15 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages [79.7 kB]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex    
Get:16 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4,505 B]
Get:17 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en [104 kB]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex  
Get:18 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en [2,038 B]
Get:19 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en [2,268 B]
Get:20 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en [46.3 kB]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex      
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://www.ubnt.com stable/ubiquiti Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://www.ubnt.com stable/ubiquiti Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Err http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti i386 Packages

Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti Translation-en_US             
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti Translation-en                
Err http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti amd64 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Err http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti i386 Packages                 
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main Translation-en_US              
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Fetched 913 kB in 25s (35.6 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
# sudo apt-get update
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic InRelease                
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg       
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates InRelease               
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release                     
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu InRelease                                       
Hit http://www.ubnt.com stable InRelease                                       
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports InRelease                 
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic Release.gpg                         
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu Release.gpg                           
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates Release.gpg       
Get:1 http://www.ubnt.com stable/ubiquiti amd64 Packages [687 B]     
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports Release.gpg               
Get:2 http://www.ubnt.com stable/ubiquiti i386 Packages [687 B]      
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic Release                             
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates Release           
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports Release         
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main Sources/DiffIndex    
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu Release                               
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex        
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex       
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti amd64 Packages/DiffIndex     
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti i386 Packages/DiffIndex      
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Sources      
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Sources          
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex    
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Sources            
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Sources          
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex  
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages   
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages     
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages          
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en         
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en   
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex      
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://www.ubnt.com stable/ubiquiti Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://www.ubnt.com stable/ubiquiti Translation-en                
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti Translation-en_US
Ign http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti Translation-en
Err http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://www.ubnt.com ubuntu/ubiquiti i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main Translation-en_US              
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Err http://mirrors.digitalocean.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]
Fetched 1,374 B in 29s (45 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.241.164.26 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
# sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unifi : Depends: binutils but it is not going to be installed
         Conflicts: unifi-controller
 unifi-beta : Conflicts: unifi-controller
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
# sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Err Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]                                        
Err Upgrade tool                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]                                        
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
WARNING:root:file 'vivid.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Comment: The normal method is to use the `do-release-upgrade` command. There should be no "checking/editing files" needed. Best practice is to uninstall all packages from non-Ubuntu sources, and to do a full data backup, before starting - those two actions prevent the two most common problems. Beyond that, please edit your question to explain the problem you have in plenty of detail - what you tried, how it failed, and the complete output including all error messages.

Comment: Reviewers: afaik questions about *how to upgrade from* EoL releases are on topic, though it is often sensible to close them as duplicates of the suggested post. Dylan DeCrausaz: if you have tried the suggestions in the linked post, please be specific about what you tried, explain what is happening or not happening as a result, and give exact commands and error messages if possible, please!

Comment: There are several problems. 1. You are trying to upgrade from an end-of-life release; 2. The upgrade path from a standard release (which is not an LTS release) is to the next release, 14.10 ---> 15.04, and that release has also passed end of life too (as well as the next release, 15.10). I think the upgrading path via several releases will be very difficult. I would recommend that you install a fresh system of the newest release with long time support, 16.04 LTS.

Comment: change the URL for all Ubuntu sources to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com then `sudo apt-get update` and `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: @ravery I attempted these steps and included the output in the sample above.

I understand the recommendation to start with a fresh install, however this is acting as an active cloud server that I cannot chance breaking. Is there no way to successfully follow the upgrade path methodically?

Comment: remove the digital ocean mirrors, then try again. the old-release archive should have a upgrade file. if not it can be done manually, or do a fresh install of a newer version. Message me if you want me to post how to manually upgrade.

Comment: @ravery I would absolutely message you if I could figure that out on this site, hope this will suffice. Pretty clueless as to how to remove the digital ocean mirrors; a manual upgrade guide would be life saving.

Comment: I can't find the answer I wrote for someone else. and they closed this question so cannot post an answer here. However; I did find a guide. You just have to set your sources list for ubuntu repos instead of the debian repos shown. Guide - https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-debian-wheezy-to-jessie-stable-release/   Source list generator - https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/